# Reset Normals directions to object rotation after applyed scale

Tags: normals, scale, gizmo

I hope im not missing something easy,but i have this problem.

Was moving with gizmo by normals this object and was all right.Had to Apply Rotation and Scale,and after that the normal gizmo just reset and i can only move it like if its on "global"(Transformation Orientation bar on the top centre),wich is crazy bad in this case

How to set them back to the right value ?

I saw an answer saying to duplicate before applying,then use Data Transfer mod to set that back..Now i dont know it sounds like a workaround(maybe im wrong,it just sounds that way to me))is there any other method maybe just some option or shortcut or something like that ?

Thanks in advance,and sorry for bad english

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you in object mode or edit mode? Either way, applying rotation resets the orientation of the object.  But what you can do (and this is better) is use the 3D cursor tool to snap the 3D cursor to the geometry, and use 3D cursor transform orientation. You can create an empty with the 3D cursor's rotation and create a custom transform orientation, too. It will create the orientation from whatever is the active selection.
[image: transform orientation menu]

Comment: Thanks i will def try that ! Your gif doesnt move unfortunately for me..I even tried to save it and open again but nothing..Is it just me or u can see it moving ?

Comment: That's because it's not an animated gif! I was just showing the menu location.